# When i click on continue it should scroll page in Bootstrap Tour

Tags: jquery, odoo

i have following step tour

```
   {
            waitNot:   'h1#blog_post_name:empty()',
            element:   'h1[data-oe-expression="blog_post.name"]',
            placement: 'top',
            title:     _t("Change Title, subtitle"),
            content:   _t("Write a title, the subtitle is optional."),
            popover:   { next: _t("Continue") },

        },
        {
            element:   '#blog_content',
            placement: 'top',
            title:     _t("Content"),
            content:   _t("Start writing your story here. Click on save in the upper left corner when you are done."),
        },            
        {

            waitNot:   '#blog_content .container.readable:empty()',
            element:   'button[data-action=snippet]',
            placement: 'right',
            title:     _t("Layout Your Blog Post"),
            content:   _t("Use well designed building blocks to structure the content of your blog. Click 'Insert Blocks' to add new content."),
            popover:   { fixed: true },
        },
```

Now when i click on continue in first step "Change title,subtitle" it goes to next "Content" . Problem is that "#blog_content" div at bottom so i have manually scroll the page to view the next step.
I want that it directy scroll page to that div .. So for that what i have to do ???

You can also see this problem in video..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6tkUX6oLc8
Time : 0.30 to 0.50

Answer (score 3):

Probably a bit late for this answer but make sure you have

```
autoScroll: true
```

In your top level tour definition, as described in the API

http://bootstraptour.com/api/

Comment: Mat Jenkins
Thanks for your response and you are right for this solution. But now there is need of this thing. i made the one function in js of odoo framework which scroll the element if element id not on screen,
Thanks again for your reply.